# API call to Sharepoint from AURA using a system user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, rest-api, sharepoint

I am calling an API service to receive a list from Sharepoint (url) via a component (controller/helper .js) using `req.open("GET", url, true);`
Now I need to always call this service under a specific system user context in order to receive this list no matter which user will trigger the component in the UI. Is there a way to handle this directly in the aura or do I need to go into apex controller?

Comment: How are you handling the security aspects (authentication etc.) from an Aura component? Bear in mind that JAVAScript code is a Client code and visible to the Browser and can be viewed by end users (Using the browser Console).

Comment: Hence my question. But maybe there is an option to pass a user parameter (not whole credentials) via rest to tell which user should be used instead of the one which triggered it e.g. from salesforce component?